# How to print a variable into selenium find_element? into the text area

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

how can i print a variable into the find_element? i want to put my storaged info on the text camp of my chrome, but i can't link the find_element with my variable "rota1"

```
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd
import re

 
# THIS IS THE CODE THAT I WANT TO LINK WITH TEXTBOX 
# WHEN I CLICK ON BUTTON IT WILL BE SAVED ON VARIABLES
# OBS: i will create 9 copy of the following code, one for each textbox

    
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
        

    
        def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
            MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
            MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
            MainWindow.resize(300, 300)
            MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 300))
            MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 300))
            self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
            self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
            self.formLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
            self.formLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 281, 231))
            self.formLayoutWidget.setObjectName("formLayoutWidget")
            self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.formLayoutWidget)
            self.formLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
            self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
        
        
            self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
            self.rota = self.lineEdit
            self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
            self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.SpanningRole, self.lineEdit)
            
        
            self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
            self.rota2 = self.lineEdit_2
            self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
            self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.SpanningRole, self.lineEdit_2)

        
            self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
            self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
            self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.SpanningRole, self.lineEdit_3)

        
            self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
            self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
            self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.SpanningRole, self.lineEdit_4)

        
            self.lineEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
            self.lineEdit_5.setObjectName("lineEdit_5")
            self.formLayout.setWidget(4, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.SpanningRole, self.lineEdit_5)

        
            self.lineEdit_6 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
            self.lineEdit_6.setObjectName("lineEdit_6")
            self.formLayout.setWidget(5, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.SpanningRole, self.lineEdit_6)

        
            self.lineEdit_7 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
            self.lineEdit_7.setObjectName("lineEdit_7")
            self.formLayout.setWidget(6, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.SpanningRole, self.lineEdit_7)

        
            self.lineEdit_8 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
            self.lineEdit_8.setObjectName("lineEdit_8")
            self.formLayout.setWidget(7, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.SpanningRole, self.lineEdit_8)

    
            self.lineEdit_9 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
            self.lineEdit_9.setObjectName("lineEdit_9")
            self.formLayout.setWidget(8, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.SpanningRole, self.lineEdit_9)

        
            self.b1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            self.b1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 232, 281, 41))
            self.b1.setObjectName("b1")
            self.b1.clicked.connect(self.clicked)
        
            MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
            self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
            self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 300, 21))
            self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
            MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
            self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
            self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
            MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

            self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
            QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
            _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
            MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Route manager in python"))
            self.b1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enviar")) 
    
        def rota():
            rota = self.rota
            
        def rota2():
            rota2 = self.rota2
        
        def clicked(rota, rota2):
            
            servico = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
            navegador = webdriver.Chrome(service=servico)
            navegador.get("https://www.google.com.br/maps/dir//")
            sleep(5)
            navegador.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="sb_ifc50"]/input').send_keys(rota) # this one is fixed
            navegador.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="sb_ifc50"]/input').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
            navegador.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="sb_ifc51"]/input').send_keys(rota2)#this one will change by every texbox
            navegador.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="sb_ifc51"]/input').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)   
            sleep(5)
            kmtotal=navegador.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/div[3]/div[9]/div[9]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div')
            km1 = kmtotal.text
            value = km1.replace('km', '').replace(',', '.').replace(' ', '')
            kma = float(value)

            print(kma)
            print(self.rota.text())
            print(self.rota2.text())
            #print(self.lineEdit.text())
            #print(self.lineEdit_2.text())
            #print(self.lineEdit_3.text())
            #print(self.lineEdit_4.text())
            #print(self.lineEdit_5.text())
            #print(self.lineEdit_6.text())
            #print(self.lineEdit_7.text())
            #print(self.lineEdit_8.text())
            #print(self.lineEdit_9.text())
                
            
      #  def kma(self):
            #destino = input()
            #destinob = input()


        
        

        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
clicked("rota", "rota2")
```

ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this ignore this

Answer (score 0):

You can pass those variables into function declaration and use it in the 'send_keys':

```
def clicked(var_1, var_2):
            
            servico = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
            navegador = webdriver.Chrome(service=servico)
            navegador.get("https://www.google.com.br/maps/dir//")
            sleep(5)
            navegador.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="sb_ifc50"]/input').send_keys(var_1) # this one is fixed
            navegador.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="sb_ifc50"]/input').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
            navegador.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="sb_ifc51"]/input').send_keys(var_2) #this one will change by every texbox
            navegador.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="sb_ifc51"]/input').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)   
            sleep(5)
            ...


clicked("value1", "value2")
```

Comment: i got this error "TypeError: object of type 'Ui_MainWindow' has no len()"

I put my whole code in the post, now you can see my amateur structure